# How to use react native components in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a mobile app built on React Native. What approach can I take to use code from this mobile app into a ReactJS website?

Comment: Most of React Native is similar to ReactJS except in React JS you use actual html tags in your rendering where React Native uses a lot of its own tags for their elements in the rendering

Comment: `create-react-app` supports React Native with minimal configuration.

Comment: @Premkumarreddy Nagarapu .. hello? can you give some feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out Expo wich provides expo web wich actually works pretty decent and gets you to use web very fast and easy.

But I guess you used plain ReactNative so maybe check out this: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

You also could do a platfrom check in your app and if the detected platform is web render different elements.

Faded~